# I can't extract files in program files folder

Tags: wix

I'm working on custom action and wix.The files are not extracting in program files (x86) folder.But the files are extracting correctly other than program files (x86).  I have written code using .NET FRAMEWORK 4.0.

namespace Installer
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("Begin Extracting");
            string FinalPath = session["APPDIR"];``
            string zPath = @"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\Install\7za.exe";

```
        string ExtractPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Samples\";
        string sourcePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Samples\source.zip";

        try`
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo();``
            pro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pro.FileName = zPath;
            pro.Arguments = "x \"" + sourcePath  + "\" -o" + ExtractPath;
            Process x = Process.Start(pro);
            x.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (System.Exception Ex)
        {
        }
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to debug it properly. You're throwing away any error that might be thrown. Sorry to say this, but your question is unfortunately more like "how can I find out why my code is not working when I've thrown away any exceptions it might raise?"

There's no guarantee that the zip extension will work correctly just by starting it. It might work if WinZip is installed, but not if all that happens is that Explorer opens to look at the files.

You should use the classes that will unzip it. Example here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx